# Cannot acces "VariableName" before initialisation

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Object from "./Object";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Object />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
  let Object = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Random title");
  const Handler = () => {
    if (text === "Random title ") {
      setText("Hello arif");
    } else {
      setText("Random title");
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{text} </h1>;<button onClick={Handler}>Click me </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default Object;
```

This is my code.Whenever I click for preview in the browser it shows a error called "cannot access 'Object' before initialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you name a component Object? Also remove the `;`. Try this:

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";

  export const Title = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("Random title");
    const Handler = () => {
      if (text === "Random title ") {
        setText("Hello arif");
      } else {
        setText("Random title");
      }
    };
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{text} </h1>
        <button onClick={Handler}>Click me </button>
      </>
    );
  };
```

and then import:

```
import { Title } from "./Title";
```

Comment: It worked thanks for the answer

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote. No problem.